# How to know in which distribution is present one command

Tags: distribution-choice, command

How can I know the Linux distribution of the command?

For example, `lscpu` command

Is there any place with a matrix (distribution, commands)?

Comment: Is your question about finding out the name of the current distribution or the commands available at some distribution?

Comment: @NlightNFotis, I really don't agree with you editing the question to suit your interpretation. I think that is shocking, it should be for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @Graeme I don't know what you find shocking about it, I only made it's meaning more clear. Anyway, that's why I said, roll it back if you disagree. I'm curious however, what is **your** intrepretation of the question?

Comment: @Michel, are you trying to determine if a particular command is present on the system or are you trying to use a command to determine which distribution you are on?

Comment: Let's determine what the OP wants before we lock in on our answers and then shape the Q to suite it. Minor adjustments are fine but leave a comment if you're unclear which way to skew the Q.

Comment: @slm Sounds fair, honestly, but then again if the wording of the question itself is ambiguous, then we should look at the title of the question. The title clearly asks how can someone find out if a "command" (binary) is available at his distribution.

Comment: @NlightNFotis you can add 'with' to the title to get this - 'How to know in which distribution is present with one command?' That is basically how I read it.

Comment: I completely understand the dilemma, just ask the OP and wait, it's annoying but the safest course.

Comment: @Graeme While I still disagree with this, the way you put it is generating genuine confusion. So I can now understand why you interpreted it that way, therefore, removing my downvote.

Comment: I want to know in which distributions is present the command. lscpu just for example. Where I must find how many omnipresent is one command.

Answer (score 2):

Very few commands are distribution specific.

Each command is contained in some package, which might be installed or not.

Which packages are installed can be choosen when installing and later additional packages can be added or removed.

Therefore two boxes running the same distribution can provide a very different set of commands.

Answer (score 0):

This command is probably what you are looking for:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Since `lsb` stands for 'Linux Standard Base', it is reasonable to expect this to be present.

http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/lsbrelease.html

Comment: -1. How does this answer the op's question? The op is asking if there is a way to find out if a particular binary is on his system. `lsb_release` prints details about the particular distribution, such as its codename, etc. Apart from that, even if you check out your lsb version against the online specifications, you still may be missing out on extra binaries that are not present in the lsb specification. Not to mention that this command isn't omnipresent. My fedora 19 box doesn't have it.

Comment: @NlightNFotis Ok, this question is ambiguous, my interpretation comes from this part 'How can I know in which linux distribution is present'. Notice that while I still think mine is correct, it is not accompanied with a downvote. I was only asking why you think otherwise.

Comment: dude, please, don't take it personally. I don't downvote out of malice or revenge or anything. I downvote questions that I perceive to contain wrong or irrelevant information. In that spirit, if you consider my answer to contain wrong/irrelevant information, please downvote it to oblivion.

Comment: The question is absolutely unclear and should be edited to at least be grammatically correct so as to not elicit such confusion.

Comment: @DopeGhoti There, I edited the question to what I perceive the op wants. If you think my interpretation is wrong, please rollback the edit.

Comment: @Graeme I want to remove my downvote for this answer, but the system says that it needs to be edited, because my vote is locked. Please proceed with doing one minor edit, so I can change my vote on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could always attempt to run the command in your shell of choice. If the command is present, it will be executed. If it's not present, the shell will output something along the lines of:

```
bash: lelos: command not found...
```

Keep in mind that certain binaries may not be able to be found, unless you attempt to execute them as `root` user, or with `root` privileges (via `sudo` for instance)

Apart from that, you can use `which`. `which` is a software that searches your `$PATH` for what was given as input, and if the executable is present it will output something like

```
[23:51:20] nlightnfotis@mars : [~] $ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

If the command isn't there, it will output either nothing or something along the lines of:

```
/usr/bin/which: no <command> in $PATH
```

Keep in mind that this is not 100% reliable, as `which` only searches in your `$PATH` environment variable, and it may miss executables not located in one of the folders described in it.

Comment: Nice, but how does any of this determine the distro?

Comment: @Graeme It doesn't. The op's question **isn't** about what distro he is running. It's about how he can find out if a particular command (binary) is available at his system.

Comment: Btw, just to be clear, it wasn't me that downvoted this. Honestly I think its mad if we all downvote each other because we have different interpretations of a poorly asked question.

Comment: @Graeme Even if it was you, **that would be totally ok with me**. I'm not here for rep hunting, *I'm here to help and get helped*. In that spirit, I will say again, that if you consider my answer **not helpful** please downvote it.